how to restrict access to a subfolder in the network balloon using windows
helloy jobs
I've been puzzling over how to make a resource access control system for the past day. there is a shared folder (share). It contains folders by year, projects in them, and there are already folders in the projects that need to be accessed (d) point-by-point for each employee
How to organize access to the network balloon through Windows in the domain structure so that everyone can read share+years+projects, but they cannot read folders d. and if you give explicit permission to folder d to an employee, he could both read and execute
to put it simply, all domain users can read share+years+project but cannot read d
enter image description here

for those who will have the same task. I disabled inheritance for folder d and deleted the local/users group, and then the domain people lost access.how are local and domain related???

Have you checked what members are in your server's local Users group?
